# Unable to get servlet to be hooked in with @WebServlet annotation in an SBT project using Jetty 9

Tags: servlets, jetty, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin, jetty-9

I ran into the issue while working on an existing Java project which I'd converted to use SBT (was based purely on Eclipse before). There was a servlet (say `org.my.FooServlet`) that was not possible to be accessed via a web browser even though Eclipse (was still using Eclipse with sbteclipse) was reporting that `/FooServlet` was mapped to `org.my.FooServlet`.

So in order to rule out some issues possibly stemming from having converted the project to use SBT (e.g. some missing dependencies, or hidden or seemingly unrelated (mis)configuration issues), I went ahead and created a fresh SBT project to try to reproduce the issue with minimal complexity. So I currently have the below configuration/code/output and am still experiencing the issue:

**`container:start` output:**

```
[info] jetty-9.1.0.v20131115
[info] Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@33c4522{/,[file:/Users/erik.allik/code/scala/webtest/src/main/webapp/],AVAILABLE}
[info] Started ServerConnector@52879ec6{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 25.11.2013 14:39:34
```

**`build.sbt`:**

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.1.0.v20131115" % "container",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-jsp" % "9.1.0.v20131115" % "container",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-servlet" % "9.1.0.v20131115" % "container",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-servlets" % "9.1.0.v20131115" % "container",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-annotations" % "9.1.0.v20131115" % "container",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-plus" % "9.1.0.v20131115" % "container",
  "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" artifacts (Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar"))
)

seq(webSettings :_*)
```

**`project/plugins.sbt`:**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.4.2")
```

**`src/main/java/webtest/TestServlet.java`:**

```
package webtest;
// ...
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/test" }, loadOnStartup = 1)
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override public void init() { System.out.println("init"); }
    @Override protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) { System.out.println("GET"); }
}
```

**`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`:** (removing it altogether makes no difference)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" metadata-complete="false">
</web-app>
```

The container is reloaded whenever I edit and save either of the 2 code files, and the files are compiled, so at least SBT is picking them up; now the question is, why isn't Jetty. I've also tried (within the original project, not the test-dummy one) copying all classes from under `target/scala-2.10/classes` to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for Jetty Annotations was [added in version 0.7.0](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/notes/0.7.0.markdown#changelog).  Update xsbt-web-plugin in your *plugins.sbt* and you should be good to go:

*project/plugins.sbt:*

```
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.7.0")
```

I also recommend adding a *build.properties* to maintain control over the version of sbt that your project uses:

*project/build.properties:*

```
sbt.version=0.13.1
```

Here is a complete, working example: https://earldouglas.com/ext/stackoverflow.com/questions/20179351/

Comment: I was the one who reported it I think (or at least I remember participating in the comments), so I already knew this worked! But good to have this on Stack Overflow now!

Answer (score 0):

The `@WebServlet` call will need to be found via annotation/class scanning.

Your list of dependencies for Jetty is missing the entire feature-set for annotation scanning.

Add these too.

```
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-annotations" % "9.0.7.v20131107" % "container",
"org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-plus" % "9.0.7.v20131107" % "container",
```

Comment: Actually I was about to edit my question and amend these—I have them in `libraryDependencies` and still nothing; I've also tried adding a `jetty-web.xml` with settings for `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.setConfigurationClasses` to contain `org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration`, but this actually causes a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in file:/.../WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml`, and I have not been able to determine the cause for this.

Comment: The [embedded-servlet-3.0](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-servlet-3.0/) examples might help, particualarly the [Configurations List](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-servlet-3.0/blob/master/src/test/java/com/company/foo/EmbedMe.java#L25-L29).

Comment: Yeah, but see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192300/java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-in-jetty-web-xml-when-setting-webapp —it doesn't seem to be possible to add `AnnotationConfiguration` to `WebAppContext.configurationClasses` via `jetty-web.xml`.

Comment: No, that's too late to add them. Those are server side. Will answer in other question.