# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in jetty-web.xml when setting WebAppContext.configurationClasses

Tags: jetty, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin, jetty-9

I'm trying to add `org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration` to the `configurationClasses` property of `org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext` but (when invoking Jetty with `sbt containe:start`), getting:

```
[warn] Config error at <Set name="configurationClasses">
[warn]         <Array type="java.lang.String"><Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item><Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration</Item><Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration</Item><Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Item><Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item><Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item><Item>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration</Item><Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item></Array>
[warn]     </Set>java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in file:/Users/erik.allik/code/scala/webtest/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml
[warn] Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@33acb4a1{/,[file:/Users/erik.allik/code/scala/webtest/src/main/webapp/],STARTING}
```

I've tried changing the `<Set ...>` to a `<Call name="setConfigurationClasses">` (with both the `String[]` as well as `List<String>` variants) to no avail—still getting the same reflection exception every time.

My `jetty-web.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="configurationClasses">
        <Array type="java.lang.String">
            <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
            <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration</Item>
            <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration</Item>
            <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Item>
            <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
            <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item>
            <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration</Item>
            <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
        </Array>
    </Set>
</Configure>
```

**ANSWER:** deciding by https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/src/jetty-9/scala/Jetty9Runner.scala, xsbt-web-plugin sets the configurations property of `WebAppContext` to a hardcoded value, so no matter what's in the XML configs, it probably simply gets ignored (or causes an error, apparently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Configuration classes exist to configure the `WebAppContext` itself.

Adding the Configurations in the `jetty-web.xml` or the Jetty IoC XML Context Deployable is too late in the lifecycle.

If you look at `etc/jetty-annotations.xml` you'll see ...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Add annotation Configuring classes to all webapps for this Server -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration$ClassList" name="setServerDefault">
    <Arg><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
    <Call name="addBefore">
      <Arg name="beforeClass">org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Arg>
      <Arg>
        <Array type="String">
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration</Item>
        </Array>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

and `etc/jetty-plus.xml` you'll see ...

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Configure extended support for webapps                          -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Add plus Configuring classes to all webapps for this Server -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration$ClassList" name="setServerDefault">
    <Arg><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
    <Call name="addAfter">
      <Arg name="afterClass">org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration</Arg>
      <Arg>
        <Array type="String">
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
          <Item>org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration</Item>
        </Array>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

If you notice, you'll see that these are configured at the server level, and are based on existing defaults (to satisfy ordering requirements of the Configurations).

Comment: How about the *"Applying the configurations to a single webapp"* section at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Annotations?

Comment: That documentation is for Jetty 7 (aka Servlet 2.5) - Jetty 9 documentation (aka Servlet 3.1) is at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/annotations.html - annotation scanning for servlets / filters / websockets / etc ... (aka endpoints) is not supported in the WebSocketContext.  File a bug at bugs.eclipse.org (under RT/Jetty) if you feel this is important.

Comment: "not supported in the `WebAppContext`" you meant to say?

Comment: ...in any case, when using xsbt-web-plugin and embedded Jetty, is there any way at all then to change the list of configurations other than by creating the Jetty instance directly in Java/Scala code (as opposed to having the `container:start` command of xsbt-web-plugin do that for me)?

Comment: @ErikAllik (aka RaceCondition on irc) rejoin irc please.